# Looking for localization to map Get-WinEvent -Listlog results to config .xml path

Tags: powershell, localization, get-winevent

For the eventviewer i want default viewconfigs for each entry in the event-tree. These channel_i.xml are stored under $env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Event Viewer in folders according to the tree structure. Sadly there seems to be no standard behaviour to map the Logname to its config-file location. Is there a function to get this? Target locale is german. Currently i'm using a custom function with all the exceptions in a hashtable returning the original string if it wasn't found. Main Code is

```
Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | % {
    if($windows.Contains($_.LogName)){
        writeFile $builtin (localize $_.LogName)
    }else{
        $components = $_.Logname.Split("/")
        if($components.Count -gt 1) { 
            $name = $components[1] 
            $components= $components[0].Split("-")
        }else{
            [System.Collections.ArrayList]$components= $components[0].Split("-")
            $name = $components[-1]
            $components.RemoveAt($components.Count-1)
        }
        if($components.Count -gt 2){
            $components = $components[0..1] +($components[2..($components.Count-1)] -join "-")
        }
        $path = localize ($components -join "\")
        WriteFile "$app\$path" (localize $name)
    }    
}
```

Full Code can be found under https://pastebin.com/Cn4JSmLL